# Docker compose: Springboot connect to mysql8 databases

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Im having an issue with docker-compose.
I try to implement some really basic application:

- A spring boot application
- Mysql

I created a Dockerfile for my springboot:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-11
FROM openjdk:11

WORKDIR /app
COPY target/app-ws.jar /app/app-ws.jar
CMD mvn clean install -DskipTests

EXPOSE 8092
# CMD ls
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=docker", "app-ws.jar"]
```

In my docker compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # build mysql
  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER:root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:mydbname
    ports:
      - 3309:3309
    expose:
      - 3309
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network
    
  # build app-ws
  app-ws:
    container_name: app-ws
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ../app-ws/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8092:8092
    expose:
      - 8092
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3309/mydbname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:root
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    links:
      - mysqldb:mysqldb
    networks:
      - app-network

# # # Create the private network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: local
```

My application-docker.properties contains the following informations:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3309/mydbname?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

I have 2 issues: When running docker compose up --build I do have the following errors concerning the springboot application:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:949) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:819) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
```

My second issue is that i can't connect to the database using the port 3309. I don't know what's going wrong: i use depends on to specify my app depends on mysql, i also added the environment variables with SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL, etc.

Comment: MySQL default port is 3306. Did you change it somewhere?

Comment: Try to remove the links, also depends_on doesn't prevent your application to start before the database is ready to handle the call

Comment: Yea that's right. MySQL does take time to start up. I had the same problem with docker-compose

Comment: removing depends_on didn't change anything. In fact i added after many tries. Concerning the port 3309, I set it in docker compose. I also expose mysql to port 3309.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: [This](https://github.com/psamsotha/docker-jersey-mysql/blob/5618e07a9308126979922ae6c5f447c176583345/src/main/java/org/example/resource/db/DatabaseManager.java#L50) is what I had to do in a project.

Comment: The MySQL server will listen on port 3306 unless you reconfigure the server.  The second `ports:` number and any inter-container communication need to use the standard port 3306.  `expose:` does essentially nothing in modern Compose and you can delete that block.